# Custom attribute in AD for Distribution Group in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a powershell script that will partly automate some of the AD attributes however looking at Microsoft documentation those are not available with the Set-DistributionGroup.

Here are the AD attribute I am missing to create: targetAddress, a secondary SMTP (primary creates just fine), company

Here is my script:

Skipping the connexion to the Exchange but it is in there

```
$email = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the email'
$name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Name of the DG'


New-DistributionGroup -Name $name -Alias ($email + "@mydomain")  -DisplayName $name -PrimarySmtpAddress ($email + "@mydomain") -OrganizationalUnit **name of my OU**


Set-DistributionGroup -Identity ($email + "@mydomain") -EmailAddresses ($email + "_mydomain.fr@cooperaction.mail.onmicrosoft.com") 
Set-ADGroup -Identity ($email + "@mydomain") -Add @{Company= "mycompany"; targetAddress= $email +"_mydomain@cooperaction.mail.onmicrosoft.com"}
```

So the DG creates fine and all but as mentionned above some parameter don't get updated second bit with the Set-ADGroup fail probably because it is not meant for DG I have tried with Set-DistributionGroup but without success sadly.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You seem to have forgotten an `@` when calling `Set-ADGroup` - the `-Identity` argument is `($email + "mydomain")` instead of `($email + "@mydomain")`

Comment: Sorry corrected the variable as I wanted to hide the domain didn't do it correctly when I deleted the first one. When I create the variable for the email I just want it to be the first part of the email without the @ and what follows so I can pass this parameter for multiple field such a proxy and targetAddress and just concatenate it with what is needed.